# SwipeRefreshLayout with NestedScrollView and LinearLayout

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--<include-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/app_bar"-->
    <!--layout="@layout/app_bar" />-->


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="64dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/header"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarTutorial"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewAppBar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="@id/toolbarTutorial"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <!--<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/tabLayout"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>-->

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


                <!--<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content">-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutWithData"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                    <!--<TextView-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/textViewInternet"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:textColor="@color/black"/>-->


                </LinearLayout>
                <!--</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>-->
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFAB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/codelab_fab_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/codelab_fab_margin_right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_blue"
            app:fabSize="normal">

        </android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to have that the linearlayout with the data is below the "textViewAppBar". I have tried to implement a RelativeLayout but it doesn't work. Now, the data is showing to the full layout but I would like to have this below the "textViewAppBar" but the SwipeRefreshLayout shall be match_parent, any suggestions? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 50):

`app:layout_behavior` should be added to the direct child of `CoordinatorLayout`.

So you should move `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` from `NestedScrollView` to `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout ...>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout  ...>
        ...
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
            ...
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 9):

app:layout_behavior should be added to the direct child of CoordinatorLayout. and after you need to use NestedScrollView in SwipeLayout like;

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        ...
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

use this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ... your attribute here ... >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        ... your attribute here ... >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            ... your attribute here ... >

            ... your element here ...

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        ... your attribute here ... >

        ... your element here ...

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: with this the collapsible layout is not working..meaning it is not collpasing

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by myself to put the SwipeRefreshLayout as the main layout and add the rest as children

Comment: can you share snippet may be? which main layout?

Comment: @RahulPatil take a look my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You need add in your code :

```
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)
```

Comment: Where shall it be added?

Comment: @NinoFiliu when you initial recyclerView