# LinearLayout inside SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't work

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, swiperefreshlayout

I have this XML structure:

```
<ScrollView>
  <RelativeLayout>
   ..........
     <SwipeRefreshLayout>
        <LinearLayout/>
     </SwipeRefreshLayout>
          .....
  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I am trying to implement the SwipeRefreshLayout for the LinearLayout but it made my LinearLayout disappear. I have already tried to put the  LinearLayout inside a ScrollView, but it still doesn't appear. I can't remove the main parent also. It is necessary to me. 
Does anyone know how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

- Use [**`NestedScrollView`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView) instead of **`ScrollView`**.
- Add **RelativeLayout** as Child View instead of **`LinearLayout`**.

**NestedScrollView** is just like ScrollView, but it supports acting as both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions of Android.

**DEMO**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

          <RelativeLayout>
        .....
```

Comment: @K.Jor have a look https://gist.github.com/kamikat/2ba5f741f807d56a8dd7cf936571e69e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226658/swiperefreshlayout-interferes-with-scrollview-in-a-viewpager/45859590

Comment: @K.Jor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286159/swiperefreshlayout-with-nestedscrollview-and-linearlayout

Comment: nothing is working, probably because of the outer ScrollView